# vendor/assets/images not rendering images on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I started up a new application and added a theme inside vendor/assets folders.

I created a folder called images inside vendor/assets and added the following snippet to my application code:

```
# inside config/initializers/assets.rb.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

After that, I went to the console and checked my asset paths

```
>> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> ["/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/app/assets/images", "/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/app/assets/javascripts", "/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/app/assets/stylesheets", "/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/vendor/assets/fonts", "/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/vendor/assets/images", "/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/home/renatojf/Documents/Code/bhiz/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/assets/fonts", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/assets/images", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/assets/javascripts", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/assets/stylesheets", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/home/renatojf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@bhiz/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts"]
```

As you can see, the path is loading vendor/assets/images.
The problem is that all css files from the theme call images like:

```
.header-full-title {
  background-image: url("../img/colors/blue/logo_big.png");
}
```

And when I try to load the page, in development, I get a `No route matches [GET] "/img/colors/blue/logo_big.png")`

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Where is the image exactly? Is it vendor/assets/img/colors/blue/logo_big.png?

Comment: it is in vendor/assets/images/colors/blue/logo_big.png and I already tried to change the assets folder name into vendor/assets/img.. same error

Comment: Can you change the CSS to `background-image: asset-url("img/colors/blue/logo_big.png");`

Comment: Already did that too. The application console stops throwing up the error but the computed CSS on the browser console stops showing that property. Like this:

.header-full-title {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;

Comment: I think your CSS was cut off in the comment. Can you check your compiled CSS for the `background-image` line? Check under sources in the browser console, or view source and find the relevant CSS link.

Comment: css inside http://localhost:3000/assets/style-blue.self-5a3f01511091cd25676baba57205cbb5591d3e6783f8081202670ffd81f0c17f.css is :

.header-full-title {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 75px;
  background-image: asset-url("img/colors/blue/logo_big.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

Comment: css in the page, from the inspector: .header-full-title {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

Answer (score 0):

Yeah well.. somewhere I found out that, if rails is serving static images using asset-pipeline, you can call it directly without using `/img` inside the asset path.

So.. This works:

```
background-image: url("colors/blue/logo_big.png");
```

As well as if you put one more folder above it.. Like:

```
- vendor
--assets
----images
------img
--------colors
```